# Python Decision Tree GraphViz

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz, dot, pydot

I'm attempting to implement a Decision Tree with scikit learn and then visualise the tree with Graphviz which I understand is the standard choice for visualising DT. I'm using PyCharm, anaconda, Python 2.7 and OS X El Capitan. I've installed pydot and Graphviz with PIP install as far as I can tell and have also installed them directly in Pycharm but whatever I do I continuously get a 'No module named graphviz'.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
#import graphviz as gv
# uncommenting the row above produces an error
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
iris = load_iris()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
with open('graph.dot', 'w') as file:
    tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file = file)
file.close()
```

At the moment running this code produces the graph.dot but I cannot view the file. 
1. How do I get the graphviz repository to work? 
2. How do I write the graph to PDF/PNG? I saw some examples but non-worked
3. I found this command: dot -Tps filename.dot -o outfile.ps 
Where do I used it? And how can I verify a dot utility exists on my OS X?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I installed graphviz using homebrew, but it looks like you can also download a binary from http://www.graphviz.org/Download_macos.php. If you can't get pydot to work, you'll need to run the `dot` command from the terminal, or in you script using subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['dot', '-Tpdf', 'tree.dot', '-o' 'tree.pdf'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use following code for exporting to pdf.

First install pydot2

```
pip install pydot2
```

Then you can use following code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
iris = load_iris()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
import pydot 

dot_data = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data) 
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
graph.write_pdf("graph.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have/want graphviz on your system you can also open the .dot files as text and copy the content to [webgraphviz](http://webgraphviz.com/) which will then create and display the tree for you.

The result is not a picture or file that you can save, though, and you'd have to do this manually for every tree you created. For more complicated and/or batch tree building you'll need the actual [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) on your system, so you can call the `dot` program either from terminal or directly out of Python, as maxymoo described.